# compiling ncurses code with gcc -lncurses flag seems to not be working

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, ncurses

I'm writing a terminal based Tetris game using ncurses. I've segregated all of the ncurses code into a file called tetrisUI.c which i include a header file for in my main.c source file. When I compile all of the ncurses functions raise compiler errors. I have included ncurses.h in my source file and I'm using the -lncurses flag in gcc. I'm compiling from a makefile with the following contents:

```
Tetris : tetris.o main.o tetrisUI.o
    gcc tetris.o main.o tetrisUI.o -o Tetris

tetrisUI.o : tetrisUI.c
    gcc -std=c99 -c tetrisUI.c -lncurses

tetris.o : tetris.c tetris.h
    gcc -std=c99 -c tetris.c

main.o : main.c tetris.h tetrisUI.h
    gcc -std=c99 -c main.c
```

I was able to compile a few short test programs using ncurses just fine. This is my first attempt at using ncurses and my first significant c program (I've done a little c++ in school). I have a hunch that my problem has something to do with my makefile but I'm a noob at using those too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `-lncurses` at the link stage not at the compile stage:

```
gcc tetris.o main.o tetrisUI.o -o Tetris -lncurses
```

Comment: Well it looks like it's compiling and linking now. I wish I could say my program is actually working but that's another topic.

Answer (score 3):

You can simplify your Makefile by using default macros and rules:

```
CFLAGS = -std=c99   # C compiler flags
LDLIBS = -lcurses   # curses

Tetris : tetris.o main.o tetrisUI.o  # make does a "$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDLIBS)" on its own
```

That's all you need. The following definitions and rules can be completely omitted - make does the right thing by default:

```
CC     = gcc        # C compiler name

tetrisUI.o : tetrisUI.c  tetrisUI.h # make does a "$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<" on its own

tetris.o : tetris.c tetris.h

main.o : main.c tetris.h tetrisUI.h
```

A bit of explanation: `$@` is whatever is being built, `$<` is the first dependency, `$^` is all of them. Judicious use of this makes for less typing (and less idiotic errors, where you add a dependency and don't process it; or omit a dependency (and thus don't redo the build if it changes)). Take a look at the make manual, if you have GNU make, its info file has lots of detailed examples and tips.